# Deleting and extending the partition from a windows-linux dual boot

Tags: linux, partitioning

I'm following the steps mentioned in this site
[Removing linux from TN government laptop](http://deezthomas.com/blog/9-tutorials/1-how-to-make-the-tn-govt-laptop-awesome.html?showall=1&limitstart=)

It is clear till step 5, I can simply delete the linux partition and make it as a new drive. Do I have to delete the D drive also and make a single large unallocated partition?
What happens if I delete only the linux partition and then making a new drive from the space obtained leave D drive as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'd have three partitions, pretty much, and not much more. Windows would pick them up as such. The person who wrote the post has those instructions since he seems to be trying to make a single large partition (as most windows systems would have), and eliminating most of the customisations. Its a matter of personal preference really.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I delete the linux partition and create a new drive that windows would detect it, and the new partition will come under extended partition?

Comment: I can't remember if an extended partition must be the last partition or not, offhand. You can choose when you format it from windows if you can - and its optional. With 3 partitions tho, you can choose to go either way.

Comment: I've created a new partition from the space obtained by deleting the linux partition...